# Cannot get Opensuse/Windows11 to full screen in Virtual Box in MX Linux

Tags: virtualbox, fullscreen

I use Virtual Box in my MX Linux to try different distros without harming my system. Previously, I tried Pop OS in the Virtual Box, and it ran smooth, and I could use that in full screen. However, when I tried to do the same for Windows11 and Opensuse, I failed. There is an option named Insert guest additions Image under the devices tab as far as I knew. Using that, the black screen surrounding the OS window could be removed by me, and the OS would take on the whole screen in the full-screen mode. However, that does not work either.
Here, I am sharing the pictures for the demonstration.

Below is the picture, where you can see that the OS screen is not in full screen.
[image: OS window not in full screen]

And the other picture shows that "the Insert Guest Additions Image" cannot be run due to some unknown error.

[image]

Is there any way to solve this issue? Please let me know.

Comment: What does it say when you expand the Details section of the error?  This issue is usually resolved by the installation of the Guest Additions, so that is the issue needing resolved here

Comment: I have updated the post, and in the details: it is said that it could not mount the media drive.

Comment: Does nobody have a solution to that?

Answer (score -1):

The problem was solved when I switched to VMware workstation free version for Linux. I just had to install open vmware-tools to make the guest OS go full screen. Maybe the problem lies in the Virtualbox application, not sure, though.